# git rebase equivalent of merge --squash

Tags: git

I've got a rather messy branch on my hands. It has undergone several instances of

```
git merge master
```

If I do the git rebase -i with a lot of squashed, I'll have to re-fix the conflicts that I resolved in the merges.

My impression is that

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash
```

would end up with the desired result without the manual remerging. Is my best bet:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b clean-new-branch
git merge --squash my-messy-branch
```

and the reset my branch onto the end of clean-new-branch, abandoning my prior history?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following history:

```
     master               my-messy-branch
        ↓                        ↓
-- C -- C -- M -- M -- M -- M -- M
```

Where `C` are “clean” (or good) commits, and `M` are “messy” ones, and you want the following result:

```
     master   my-messy-branch
        ↓       ↙
-- C -- C --- C
```

Then it’s really simple to do so, without having to do an interactive rebase with squashing all those commits manually. Instead, you can just do a soft-reset on your messy branch:

```
git checkout my-messy-branch
git reset --soft master
git commit
```

This will create a single commit for all the changes in those `M` commits.

Comment: Your picture is fine, except that I have more than one master->C event. Will this just fix the last one? Which might be enough for now.

Comment: Branches are just pointers to commits in the history, so in my example, master’s history would have two `C` commits and whatever comes before those. What my solution basically does is keep all the changes in the working directory but reset the branch pointer to master. And then you commit all those changes that are in your working directory but differ from master at once.

Comment: OK, now I get it. I was teetering on the edge of cargo-cultism before.

Comment: This did not behave as expected; after the reset, a ton of changes that came into my branch on a merge from master were sitting there unstaged. I guess I'll stick with rebase -i.